# R ggplot2 histogram bin allocation

Tags: r, ggplot2

My problem is that when I construct histograms with ggplot2 of certain bin width greater than the resolution of the data, bins sometimes contain uneven numbers of increments from the underlying data. This results in large peaks in the histogram which five a false impression of how peaky the data are. Is there a built-in way to prevent this? Maybe allocate increments between bins?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggplot2movies)
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating))
#Original resolution
plot(m + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) + scale_y_sqrt())
#Downsampled
plot(m + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25) + scale_y_sqrt())
```

[image: Original Resolution]

[image: Downsampled]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to prevent. I mean you are specifying a certain bin width and the plot shows the counts for those bins. You should just choose a bin width that's appropriate for your data. And honestly that's not a solved problem. There are different algorithms implemented in the base `hist()` function. It's peaky because histograms are meant for continuous random variables and you basically have discrete values. It's showing that your data does have some structure which is really more truthful in my opinion.

Comment: For the algorithms the base `hist` uses, see `?nclass` - you could use one of the those three options to determine the total number of bins, but they are all based on the range of the data, not the resolution. And also keep in mind that the data resolution might not be constant over its range.

Comment: @MrFlick It is for a Shiny app in which the number of bins is adjustable to facilitate comparison with other datasets. Obviously certain multiples of the resolution make the most sense as a bin width, and maybe I could restrict the values to that subset, but I would really like it to draw something sensible for intermediate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for now is to simply modify binwidth as a function of data resolution, as opposed to number of bins.

Comment: The "peakiness" is affected by the center of the bars as well as the bin width, it can be set with `center=`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if there is a built-in way or not, geom_histogram() has a default of 30 bins, which you can override.
One possible soltution can be, if you count the number of different x values and use that in the number of bins (or a fraction of them):

```
plot(m + geom_histogram(bins = nlevels(as.factor(movies$rating))))
```

[image]